# Where can I find unlocked Kombat Kodes in Mortal Kombat 9?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

When I unlock an Kombat Kode, It shows up on the screen. When I dismiss it, is there anywhere I can find my unlocked Kodes, or am I supposed to write them down?

I know I can google them all, but that's no fun, I only want to see those I honestly acquired. :)

Answer (score 2):

The codes you have unlocked are visible by selecting the following options from the main menu: Extras, Nekropolis, Design.

Unfortunately they are lumped in with all the concept art etc and they don't seem to be in any specific order.